# The requested resource not available in case of JSF

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, jsf

I am using JSF in one of my application and the scenario is as follows:

1. I have "pages" folder under "WEB"
2. in side "pages" I have "a.jsp"
3. When I deploy this application with the local tomcat and access the application it works perfectly ok
4. but when I deploy this application on my web hosting providers tomcat, it says "The requested resource (/pages/a.jsp) is not available."

In short the thing works perfectly OK on my local server but when I deploy this on my hosting providers tomcat, says requested resource not available.

Comment: what does your web.xml look like?

Comment: Why did you change `WEB-INF` in your question to `WEB`? Now it has an entirely different meaning which would make my answer possibly invalid.

Comment: @Balusc Yes, I have corrected the question!

Comment: @Bozho actually I had earlier version of my build deployed over my web hosting provider tomcat, and I dont know how they deploy the new .WAR. can that be a issue?

Answer (score 0):

> but when I deploy this application on my web hosting providers tomcat, it says "The requested resource (/abc/a.jsp) is not available."

What is the *context root* of the webapp deployed on your hosted server. What is the name of the `.war` file? Do you provide any `context.xml`? How do you actually access it? And how do you access your app on your local server?

Comment: This is how I access my application on my local machine: http://localhost:8080/MyApp/pages/a.jsf and this is how I access my application on the hosting service providers tomcat www.myapp.com/pages/a.jsf The name of my war is MyApp.war. I am able to access other pages which are not under "pages" folder for ex: www.myapp.com/index.jsf

Comment: @Abhishek Are you sure the application is deployed on `/`? What do you get at http://www.myapp.com/MyApp/abc/a.jsf?

Comment: Yes it is and I get the same "The requested resource" at myapp.com/MyApp/abc/a.jsf

Comment: Infact I have a filer defined for the /pages/* URL, even that seems to be not invoked. Is that because the WAR is not deployed properly and it is still using old web.xml. I am able to see new files and folder though.

Comment: @Abhishek I can't say, you are in contact with your hosting provider, you have the details, you have the instructions, I only suggested the most basic checks to perform in such case. I suggest contacting your provider.

Comment: @Pascal, can you tell me more about this context.xml?

Comment: @Abhishek The documentation would be a good starting point: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html. I mentioned it because you can configure a `path` in it.